# Why is it harder for women than men to do push ups?

Tags: push-ups

From the sources I could find, women find it harder than men to do push ups. Why is that?

Comment: Before commenting.. do you have proof? All women are capable of doing a pushup with proper training.. I don't know if you can compare the two. If I had to guess---Women have more type 1 muscles and handle more endurance while men have more type 2 muscles.  That being said, the muscles used are your chest, triceps, anterior deltoids, and transverse abdominus. If I had to guess, these muscles might be underdeveloped or might be harder since their muscles are built more for endurance and not strength.

Comment: Probably more of a biology + cultural impact than a physics impact. I don't think being a woman changes the physics of a pushup.

Comment: "According to the push-up standards set forth by the United States Army (20), women perform 40% to 60% fewer standard push-ups than men. For health-related assessments, women complete about 20% to 24% fewer modified push-ups than men"... https://www.google.com/url?q=https://digitalcommons.wku.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D1582%26context%3Dijes&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjO6ergntjsAhXEk4sKHTumAvQQFnoECAUQAg&usg=AOvVaw215qRakGYQ3HwIV7sDiC7c

Comment: I don’t see why anything deeper than “men have more muscle on average than women” would be necessary to answer this question. Perhaps I’m overlooking something?

Comment: @JustSnilloc The PDF I linked to above suggests several other factors. It's easy to check that it's not because of "more muscle", by comparing to other exercises. I found it hard to find any conclusive answer from that PDF, though.

Comment: I find an issue with that study is that participants needed to complete 5 pushups *as a minimum*. This means the 19 men could've easily been able to do 30 while the 18 women, maybe, could only do 5. They have that as a source of error in their discussion section: *"[...] because women on average perform fewer
push-ups than men (9), an earlier onset of
fatigue would likely be experienced by
women during a 5-rep push-up test.
Fatigue would be associated with reduced
power output [...]"*. I would've really like if they chose 20 men/women that could each do 20 pushups, and then test 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply looking at the biology of the male and female human body tells us enough to answer this question.

Men have far **higher base testosterone**, which is why men have a higher base musscle mass compared to women. Men also have a **larger and stronger bone structure** and **more lung capacity**, resulting in being able to train harder than women.

Females also have **less of their muscle mass in the upperbody** compared to males, another factor that makes pushups in particular harder to do for a woman.

Answer (score 8):

Women, on average, have less muscle mass than men[<sup>1</sup>](https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/jappl.2000.89.1.81), and have a lesser proportion of their muscle in the upper body[<sup>2</sup>](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0969804397000961). These make it less likely than a random woman will have the upper body strength needed to perform a pushup compared to a random man.

The point raised by C. Lange regarding cultural impact is also an important one - if a society perceives strength training as an unfeminine activity, then the odds are further stacked against women, because a smaller proportion of women will engage in strength training compared to men.

Women do still respond to upper body strength training though[<sup>3</sup>](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4756754/), and so can certainly train to perform pushups.

Comment: @Alexander - https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5955292/

Comment: @Alexander your original question referred to "From all sources I could find". What countries were those sources from? Cultural impact will certainly vary from culture to culture, but if you're looking for information on a specific country or culture we'd need to know which it is.

Comment: The sources I could find are from the US, but I am Norwegian.

Comment: At the risk of being crass, the average female also may be carrying more mass in their chest thanks to the breasts (and a part of me wants to be sophomoric enough to start comparing the issues of touching the floor earlier versus the benefit of not having to go down as far before touching).